# Laravel 7 Spatie return same Role

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

I have a table called "roles" :

```
id | name  | guard_name | created_at          | updated_at
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | userx | web        | 2020-09-02 22:00:34 | 2020-09-02 22:00:34
2  | admin | web        | 2020-09-03 23:28:53 | 2020-09-03 23:28:53
```

and I have another table called `role_has_permissions` :

```
permission_id | role_id
-----------------------
145           | 2
146           | 2
147           | 2
151           | 3
```

another table called `model_has_roles` :

```
role_id | model_type      | model_id
-------------------------------------
1       | App\Models\User | 120
3       | App\Models\User | 3
```

When I run the command on my "MenuController.php"

```
$user = Auth::user();   
$role_user = $user->getRoleNames();
return $role_user;
```

I receive a return `["admin"]` , that is correct , because I'm logged as admin , that is model id `"3"` .

but when I run the same command on my `Menu.php` (Model) , I receive the follow return `["userx"]` .

that like the `getrolenames` only return the first permission when I run on my model.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
$user = Auth::user();   
$role_user = $user->roles->pluck('name');
return $role_user;
```

Comment: If it doesn`t work do a dd($user->roles); and check what roles are returning.